# Javascript Date acting weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Okay, I have heard about it but I can confirm now that the Javascript Date functionality is a disaster zone. And I have created a monster out of it. I have this Program :

A JSON object contains list of holiday dates and its respective label.
I need to find out the date of **5 business days** from today (excluding saturday, sunday and holiday if any which is contained in the JSON object.) Good stuff so far. Then this 5 business days' **date** is going to be devoured by the jquery calender as a **default selected date** which is not included in the fiddle as it is irrelevant. (Note: the start date on the calender is tommorow's date) Good stuff again. THEN, comes this part: If it is before noon today, I can select tommorow **else** start date is day after tommorow. I'm elaborating this because it is included in this fiddle.

So the problem is multiple initialization of the function which handles above functionality is not producing consistent result. It was calculating 5 business days on my system, but when i made this fiddle, it is calculating 4. The date of **"5th"** business days is incremental by 1 on each call.

http://jsfiddle.net/xXQ7j/27/

Anyone!

Comment: please explain the significance of calling `initDate()` four times.

Comment: it is fired when user clicks a radio button. There are four. So I'm just emulating four initDate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is *probably* caused by timezone issues.

Whenever possible you should use `new Date(y, m, d)` to create a date object, rather than supplying a string.  In particular, I've found that you get a date relative to 00:00 UTC if you specify a string in format `yyyy-mm-dd` but one relative to local midnight if you use `yyyy/mm/dd`.

In any event, I would suggest a different approach:

1. convert your holiday date into an object, with the date being the key
2. generate today's date
3. if it's after noon, get tomorrow's date - `d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)`
4. create an empty array
5. add one day (per #3 above)
6. check if the new day is Saturday or Sunday, if so, go back to #5
7. check if the new day is in the holiday list, if so, go back to #5
8. add the new date to the array
9. repeat until you have 10 entries

That should give you the next 10 business days in your array.  Pick the ones you need to fill out your date picker.

Comment: Thank you for this. After 2 days of toiling, its finally working now. Copying date was the main culprit. Date are copied by reference if used convention = operator.